# warning: trying to access array offset on value of type null in bdthemes-prime-slider-lite/modules/general/widgets/general.php on line2135

Tags: wordpress

```
$title_link_target = ( $slide_content['title_link']['is_external'] ? '_blank' : '_self' );
```

line 2135 is this. Can you help me with this error please? Wordpress

```
 $this->add_render_attribute( 'slide_content_animate', 'class', 'bdt-prime-slider-content' );
        $title_link_href = ( isset( $slide_content['title_link']['url'] ) ? esc_url( $slide_content['title_link']['url'] ) : 'javascript:void(0);' );
        $title_link_target = ( $slide_content['title_link']['is_external'] ? '_blank' : '_self' );
        $this->add_render_attribute(
            [
            'title-link' => [
            'class'  => [ 'bdt-slider-title-link' ],
            'href'   => $title_link_href,
            'target' => $title_link_target,
        ],
        ],
            '',
            '',
            true
        );
        ?>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It’s an error in the theme/plugin you’re using. You should contact the developers of the theme/plugin and ask them to fix it.